# Strapi App hosted on Heroku times out and cuts off connection before upload completes (uploads to AWS S3 Bucket)

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, connection-timeout, strapi

I've developed a strapi app and deployed it on Heroku. This app directs all uploads to an AWS S3 bucket. When I try and upload a large file, I get an h13 error (a heroku error essentially saying the connection has timed out). "Connection has closed without response". I THINK the way to solve this is to increase the timeout from strapi, which I believe has a default value of 120 seconds. Only problem is I have no idea how to do this.

Anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: facing the same issue with heroku, strapi and coudinary